# What does the error ``expected ";" before obj'' mean?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in C++ using my own header file.

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"operation.h"

using namespace std;
main()
{
  int a;
  cout <<"Enter the value a";
  cin>>a;

  //class name add
  //obj is object of add
  add obj;
  obj.fun(a);
}
```

operation.h

```
class add
{

  void  fun(int b)
  {
    int c,d=10;
    c=d+b;
    cout<<"d="<<d;
  }
}
```

When I compile using G++ in Linux, it is showing the following errors:

```
->expected ";" before obj
->obj not declared in this scope
```

How do I solve this problem? Why is this happening?

Comment: On a further note, you should start your Class names with a upper case character, as this is standard and makes the code more readable.

Comment: I'd hardly say it's standard. It's common, but how you name your classes depends on your guidelines.

Comment: If anything its non-standard given the class naming convention in the standard library... Both ways are commonplace.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `public:` at the top of class add. The default for class members is to make them private.

Also, you're missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition. C++ requires class definitions to end with a semicolon following the closing curly-brace (you could actually declare a variable at that point).

Comment: Thanks for fixing my answer, Shog9. I've been bitten by the missing semi-colon myself, it's an easy thing to miss.

Comment: @Mark: no problem - caught it while editing, and it seemed like a good fit with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the real reason for the error, but you should really insert include guards and there is a missing ; after the class definition:

```
// operation.h
#ifndef OPERATION_H
#define OPERATION_H
class add {
public:
   void fun( int b ) {
      int c = 0; // always initialize, just in case
      int d = 10;
      c = d+b;
      std::cout << "d=" << d;
   }
};
#endif
```

EDIT:
main() return type is not present. You should add a 'int' at that point.

Comment: how do you fail to see reason,but then you fix it?

Comment: I had not found the solution to the compiler error. The initial code has two small problems corrected, but none of them should trigger that compiler error: header guards are not required, but in a more complex scenario will save you from double definitions. Making the fun() method public will correct the access limitation error _after_ the real problem is solved.

Comment: Or so I thought... c++ compiler errors are sometimes a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above first "wrongness" is missing semicolon after class bracket;
second is private access violation (make this method public),

My suggestion (to keep your header file "clean") put definition of your class method into `*.cpp` file and let your header contain only declaration (you will avoid unnecessary inclusion of iostream header.)

so `*.hpp` file should contain only:

```
class add {
public:
   void fun( int b );
};
```

and `*.cpp`

```
void add::fun( int b)
{
  //here goes implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you initializing the class?  Note that the following is the correct way to instantiate a new "add" object in C++:

```
add a(params);
```

Which is *not* equivalent to the following:

```
add(params) a;
```

Subtle difference, and definitely a departure from the way some other languages do it.  Could conceivably generate the "expected ;" error.

As an aside, I agree with above commenter that classes should be capitalized and functions not.  This is a convention that makes for much greater readability, and which you will see repeated in other OO languages.  OTOH, this assumes readable code as your goal.  Whether to name using CamelCase or underscores is more subjective, and thus more contentious, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like that is not the only problem you have got:

```
$ g++ -c /tmp/ttt.cpp
In file included from /tmp/ttt.cpp:2:
/tmp/operation.h: In member function ‘void add::fun(int)’:
/tmp/operation.h:8: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/ttt.cpp: At global scope:
/tmp/ttt.cpp:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/tmp/ttt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/ttt.cpp:8: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/ttt.cpp:9: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/operation.h:4: error: ‘void add::fun(int)’ is private
/tmp/ttt.cpp:14: error: within this context
```

Make sure you address all of the errors in the header file first.